# Can I use Google+ Accounts For Identification In A Java Program?

Tags: java, passwords, storage, identity

I was thinking of using Google+ accounts for identification in my Java program, as an alternative to storing passwords(After watching: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q). Is this possible using the Google+ API's with a pure Java solution? NOTE: This is Java, not Javascript.

Comment: Don't know, what does the [API Docs](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/java) tell you? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590459/oauth-2-0-access-with-google-plus-api-in-java) might also be of interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try visiting this URL: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/#Java_Authentication_options

It describes how you can use Google API to accomplish user authentication in your Java application.