# Correct use of Google+ one-time login token

Tags: security, authentication, google-plus

In the [sample Java code for Google+ server-side authentication](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-java/blob/master/src/com/google/plus/samples/quickstart/Signin.java#L133) there is this comment within the code for handling requests to the url `/connect`:

```
    // Normally the state would be a one-time use token, however in our
    // simple case, we want a user to be able to connect and disconnect
    // without reloading the page.  Thus, for demonstration, we don't
    // implement this best practice.
    //request.session().removeAttribute("state");
```

The `state` attribute is a random sequence generated on the page load of the default route (`/`) and must be presented by the ajax call to `/connect` for the connect request to succeed.

The comment implies that it is improper for the state to remain in the session, but has been commented out simply to allow the user to log in and out repeatedly in the example.

However, I do want the user to be able to log in and out at will, without reloading the page. If I keep the value for `state` in the session am I allowing an exploit? Should I be generating a new state and updating it somewhere in the DOM on `/disconnect`? Or should I do something different altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the state value set in the session is used to prevent cross-site-request-forgery ([CSRF/XSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)). In the samples, we have a completely trusted path when performing the OAuth v2 flow so for that specific scenario token validation is redundant.

For more information about the state parameter you can look at:

- [Forming the URL](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl) (OAuth v2)
- [Confirm anti-forgery state token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#confirmxsrftoken)

[Related question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415442/authenticating-g-users-on-the-server-side-after-client-side-login/15432006#15432006).

Comment: Thank you. I understand your answer, but am still not certain if it is acceptable to reuse the same `state` value for multiple login/out requests on a single page instance, as is done in the example. (i.e. is it OK to keep the `state` attribute in the session post-login?)

Comment: It's ok to keep the state attribute in the session post-login. This value can change with subsequent requests and is a precautionary protection in OAuth flows. Adding more information.